# How to do hierarchical sorting in PHP array?

Tags: php

I want to sort a table with hierarchical keys but I can not :( Here's an example:

```
array ( '1.1.1' => 'test1', '10.1.1' => 'test2', '2.1.1' => 'test3', 1 => 'test4', 2 => 'test5', 3 => 'test6', '0.1' => 'test7', 0 => 'test8', 10 => 'test9', )
```

The result must to be :

```
array ( '0' => 'test8', '0.1' => 'test7', '1' => 'test4', '1.1.1' => 'test1', '2' => 'test5', '2.1.1' => 'test3', '3' => 'test6',  '10' => 'test9', '10.1.1' => 'test2')
```

Thank a lot !

My attempt : 
https://notepad.pw/71vyf2f7

Comment: Please show us your attempt.

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: Please, refresh, I modified my post

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at uksort? http://php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php

I think that's what you need

```
$arr = array ( '1.1.1' => 'test1', '10.1.1' => 'test2', '2.1.1' => 'test3', 1 => 'test4', 2 => 'test5', 3 => 'test6', '0.1' => 'test7', 0 => 'test8', 10 => 'test9', );



function cmp($a,$b) {
       return floatval($a) > floatval($b);
}

uksort($arr, 'cmp');

print_r($arr)
```

Comment: Thank a lot ! TommyBs

Comment: You're welcome, if the answer helped you please considering hitting the 'tick' to mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$in = [
    '1.1.1' => 'test1',
    '10.1.1' => 'test2', 
    '2.1.1' => 'test3', 
    1 => 'test4', 
    2 => 'test5', 
    3 => 'test6', 
    '0.1' => 'test7', 
    0 => 'test8', 
    10 => 'test9'
];
$desired = 
[
    '0' => 'test8', 
    '0.1' => 'test7', 
    '1' => 'test4', 
    '1.1.1' => 'test1', 
    '2' => 'test5', 
    '2.1.1' => 'test3', 
    '3' => 'test6', 
    '10' => 'test9', 
    '10.1.1' => 'test2'
];

ksort($in, SORT_NATURAL);
var_dump($in === $desired);
var_export($in);
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
array (
  0 => 'test8',
  '0.1' => 'test7',
  1 => 'test4',
  '1.1.1' => 'test1',
  2 => 'test5',
  '2.1.1' => 'test3',
  3 => 'test6',
  10 => 'test9',
  '10.1.1' => 'test2',
)
```

Comment: Thank a lot ! Progrock